# Ionic 3 :Type 'any' is not a constructor function type

Tags: angular, ionic2, native, node-modules, ionic3

I had my ionic 2 project in my linux mission when i coped and moved to the mac which has ionic 3.

So i created a new project and replaced the pages, provides, components folder with the new project i was getting error like `cannot find module "ionic-native"` after importing my plugins into app.modulte.ts file i am getting as error as 'Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.`

my terminal shows

```
17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/app-version/index.d.ts, line: 25
            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type. [17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/geolocation/index.d.ts, line: 127 [17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/google-analytics/index.d.ts, line: 30 [17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/network/index.d.ts, line: 49 [17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/sms/index.d.ts, line: 41 [17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing/index.d.ts, line: 29 [17:39:48]  typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/sqlite/index.d.ts, line: 115

      L25:  export declare class AppVersion extends IonicNativePlugin {

            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

     L127:  export declare class Geolocation extends IonicNativePlugin {

            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

      L30:  export declare class GoogleAnalytics extends IonicNativePlugin {

            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

      L49:  export declare class Network extends IonicNativePlugin {

            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

      L41:  export declare class SMS extends IonicNativePlugin {

            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

      L29:  export declare class SocialSharing extends IonicNativePlugin {

            Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

     L115:  export declare class SQLite extends IonicNativePlugin {

[17:39:48]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

in my browser i am getting error like [image: this]

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/sms": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.6",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "cordova-plugin-sms",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "kmart: An Ionic project"
}
```

after using `npm install @ionic-native/core --save` i am getting error like [image: this]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use `ionic-native` 3.x you need to install `@ionic-native/core`.

```
npm install @ionic-native/core@3.6.1 --save
```

Comment: i have tried this command `npm install @ionic-native/core --save` if i use this command i am getting error like `Cannot find module "ionic-native"`

Comment: ionic terminal is not showing me any error take a look at the image i have updated my question

Comment: ionic-native..cordova plugins dont work with serve.use a device/emulator

Comment: but i am not using any plugin i have commented all the plugin that i am using inside the code

Comment: where are you using  "cordova-plugin-app-version" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143287/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).

Answer (score 2):

I had `@ionic-native/core ^3.6.0` in my package.json. For me the problem was solved by importing my plugins like

```
import {File, Transfer, FilePath} from "ionic-native";
```

instead of

```
import {FilePath} from "@ionic-native/file-path";
import {Transfer} from "@ionic-native/transfer";
import {File} from "@ionic-native/file";
```

Answer (score 0):

yesterday i was facing the same issue after updating my pretty old version to a new one.
I had to perform a lot of steps to make it work in the end. Here is what i needed to do, or how i solved it.
First i created a 'dummy' project

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

i opened the `package.json` and compared all the versions to my current one and updated them accordingly (you might want to use `npm outdated` to see the latest and your installed versions).

Unfortunately that did not solve my issue, i could build my project, but i got the same error like you `cannot find module "ionic-native"`
after starting.

After reading a lot of posts and hints, i did the following (there were lots of other errors coming up and this is how i solved all of them).

Open the `app.module.ts` and check your imports
Before:

```
imports: [
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
   Ionic2RatingModule
]
```

After:

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
   Ionic2RatingModule,
   HttpModule /* in case you used http before */
]
```

The next important step is to search your whole code for
`import from "ionic-native"`

In case you find something like that, you have to change / update it to the new version. (Typically that is for the splashScreen and the statusBar in you app.component.ts)

Before:

```
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;    
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
    platform.pause.subscribe(e=>{

    })
  }
}
```

After:

```
 import {StatusBar} from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
 import {SplashScreen} from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
   @Component({
     templateUrl: 'app.html'
   })
   export class MyApp {
     rootPage = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();
      });
      platform.pause.subscribe(e => {

      })
    }
  }
```

Check the constructor and the imports, they changed!
I had to do all those changes for everything which was imported via  `MODULE import from "ionic-native"` like for example: `StatusBar, SplashScreen, Camera, Network, Transfer, Geolocation ...`
Also keep in mind that now you have to add them to the `providers` section in your `app.module.ts`

In case you cannot find a module anymore (like it happened to me for the Camera), make sure you import the correct ionic module `npm install --save @ionic-native/camera`

At the very end, you should not find any
`MODULE import from "ionic-native"`

again in your code.
Hope it helps somebody :)