# Ionic 2.0 - Add plugins to app module - invalid syntax?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I am attempting to add the Geolocation Ionic native plugin to my Ionic 2.0 application.

As per the instructions [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module), I have imported the geolocation plugin and I am attempting to add it to the ‘providers’ array on my AppModule decorator, but I am getting a syntax error:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    BasketPage,
    AccountPage,
    AccountCreationPage,
    CategoriesPage,
    TabsPage,
    LandingPage,
    CategoryPage,
    ProductPage
  ],
  imports: [
      IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
      HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    BasketPage,
    AccountPage,
    AccountCreationPage,
    CategoriesPage,
    TabsPage,
    LandingPage,
    CategoryPage,
    ProductPage
  ],
  providers: [
      Geolocation,
      { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The providers array seems to only accept an object with the ‘provide’ and ‘useClass’ properties, so adding the Geolocation object didn’t work.

Also, if you check the Ionic documentation, the providers array looks different to mine? Why is that? When I checked the Ionic documentation, there are only two versions - v1 and ‘latest’.

What am I doing wrong here?

The error message I get when the task runner is building the app is as follows (although Visual Studio highlights in red the syntax error anyway):

> 12:56:37] typescript:
>   …rce/Repos/Aise/Aise/AiseMobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/geolocation/index.d.ts,
>   line: 127 Type ‘any’ is not a constructor function type. L127: export
>   declare class Geolocation extends IonicNativePlugin {

For reference, here is the output from the *ionic info* command:

> cli packages:
>   (C:\Users\ciara\Source\Repos\Aise\Aise\AiseMobile\node_modules)
>
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2 ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2 global packages:
>
> Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 local packages:
>
> @ionic/app-scripts : 1.1.0 Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 Ionic
>   Framework    : ionic-angular 2.0.1 System:
>
> Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3 Node              : v6.10.3 npm
>   : 3.10.10 OS                : Windows 10

My *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "io.cordova.myappeaf9db",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jsonpath": "0.2.12",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "description": "Ionic2Tabs: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "ionic:build"
    ],
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "watch"
    ]
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the syntax error message?

Comment: I updated the original comment. Thank you.

Comment: looks like similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759991/ionic-3-type-any-is-not-a-constructor-function-type

Comment: Similar yeah but unfortunately doesn't really help as the other question is someone who is upgrading to Ionic 3.0 - I am wishing to stay with Ionic 2.0 for now in an attempt to avoid any upgrade issues with my existing app. The other question doesn't seem to relate to the same piece of code that is failing for me as well (the AppModule class).

Comment: I that case your geolocation wrapper must be 3.x + .. You may need to use the older `ionic-native 2.x` where you didnt need to inject as provider at all. Can you show your package.json?

Comment: The package.json shows the version as ^2.4.3 for the geolocation package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using `ionic-native 2.x`, you dont need to install `ionic-native/<pluginName>` package.

In the 2.x version all native plugin wrappers are included in the single core package. Also all plugin types are *global* and *static*.

In your case the usage is

```
import { Geolocation } from ionic-native // import

//To access the functions,

Geolocation.functionName()
```

You can uninstall the `ionic-native/Geolocation` package.
You also do not have to set provider in AppModule or inject in constructor.